# Can I iterate through HDFS files that begin with a specific string in java?

Tags: java, filesystems, hdfs

I am trying to read from multiple HDFS .gz files, but I only want those with yesterday's date as the start of the filename.  My files look like this:

```
/notmy-data/openSourceDatasets/Temperatures/2013-06-10T133006.gz
/notmy-data/openSourceDatasets/Temperatures/2013-06-11T153006.gz
/notmy-data/openSourceDatasets/Temperatures/2013-06-11T173006.gz
/notmy-data/openSourceDatasets/Temperatures/2013-06-11T193006.gz
```

This is what I have...

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);    
String yesterdate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
Path tpath = new Path("/notmy-data/openSourceDatasets/Temperatures/" + yesterdate + "*");
FileStatus[] status = fileSystem.listStatus(tpath);
System.out.println("["+new Date()+"] Starting tempertaure ingest...");

for (int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
    BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(fileSystem.open(status[i].getPath()))));
    String line;
while (null != (line = reader.readLine())){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

I tried this with and without the star. I always get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What is `FileStatus`?

Comment: It doesn't make it to `FileStatus` because tpath is not a file that exists.

Comment: See my answer; `Path` will not autoglob for you.

Answer (score 0):

This probably not the best way to do it, but it works....

```
Path tpath = new Path("/notmy-data/openSourceDatasets/Temperatures/");    ****changed****
FileStatus[] status = fileSystem.listStatus(tpath);
System.out.println("["+new Date()+"] Starting tempertaure ingest...");

for (int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
     ****added****
    String[] fileNameBits = status[i].getPath().toString().split("/"); 
String fileDate = fileNameBits[fileNameBits.length - 1].split("T")[0]; 
String yesterString = yesterdate.toString(); 
if (!fileDate.equals(yesterString)){
    continue;
}
    ****to here****
BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(fileSystem.open(status[i].getPath()))));
String line;
while (null != (line = reader.readLine())){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Files.newDirectoryStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
// Does globbing for you!
final DirectoryStream<Path> dirstream 
    = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("yourBaseDir"), yesterdate + '*');

for (final Path path: dirstream)
    // do stuff with "path"
```

The real answer however will have to wait until you tell what that `FileStatus` is...

Also, to open a new `BufferedReader` on a `Path` object, it is MUCH easier than what you do: use [`Files.newBufferedReader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Comment: Ah... So, `Path` is specific to your library?

Comment: Eclipse can't find DirectoryStream. I added `import java.nio.*;` because it couldn't autocomplete the class....

Comment: Uhm, so, is your Java too old or not? :p

Comment: I added the import, but it won't compile cause DirectoryStream is an undefined class.

Comment: `DirectoryStream` is in package `java.nio.file`, not `java.nio`

Comment: this method will not work since it is not native to hdfs package